# Как добавить автозагрузку "в последнюю очередь" на raspbean?

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi, raspbian, автозапуск

Скомпилировал программу в бинарник на Raspbery Pi. При запуске программы через терминал, она работает правильно, но если программа была запущена через автозапуск(использовал sudo systemctl enable ..) она начинает работать не корректно. В файл сервиса прописывал как и прямой путь к программе, так и bash скрипт, который в свою очередь запускал бинарник.

МОя задача состоит в том, чтоб при автозапуске бинарник запускался в последнюю очередь, когда загрузилось абсолютно все, как будто он запускается обычным способом, через терминал. Как это сделать???

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема именно в зависимостях - то выясните какие зависимости этой программе нужны, и добавьте инструкции `After=…` и `Requires=…` в unit-файл.

Если же проблема именно в запуске от имени пользователя - вам придётся выяснить чем окружение терминала отличается от системного и исправить различия следующими директивами:

- `WorkingDirectory=` настраивает рабочую (текущую) директорию для скрипта
- `Environment="name=value"` настраивает переменные окружения
- `User=…` настраивает имя пользователя (что полезно когда требуется выдать скрипту права)
- `BindPaths`/`MountImages` пригодится если скрипту нужны данные на несистемном носителе (скажем, на SD-карте или USB-флешке)
- `AmbientCapabilities=…` если скрипту нужна какая-то особая привилегия для работы (например, привилегия `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` позволяет прослушивать привилегированные порты, такие как 80й)